# Local i variable in C?

Tags: c

I heard from a programmer (actually an IT teacher) that I should never write this:

```
void foo(bool foobar) {
   if(foobar) {
      size_t i;
      for (i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
         // Do something
      }
   } 
}
```

But this:

```
void foo(bool foobar) {
   size_t i;
   if(foobar) {
      for (i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
         // Do something
      }
   } 
}
```

Why?

Moreover, it seems that `size_t` is also bad because using a unsigned value prevent the compiler to do a good optimization.

Comment: For the first question, I belive that most compilers don't give a damn, and will extract it if needed. The liveliness of the variable is all that matters, and since it's not assigned directly, I would say you don't care. However, it is often clearer to keep all your variables at the beginning of a function. For the second one, why would unsigned prevent optimizations? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889707/compiler-optimization-on-marking-an-int-unsigned)

Comment: For simple sanity checks whether you have outsmarted the compiler, try [godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) first.

Comment: Why didn't you ask the programmer/IT teacher who told you that? It would be interesting to know what the answer is.

Comment: Have a polite conversation with your IT teacher as to why their convention is no longer idiomatic.

Comment: Probably your IT teacher is used to run gcc with pedantic mode and with the C89 standard. With that standard, you must put your declaration at the beginning of your scope. But in reality there is no special rule...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's nonsense. Always reduce the scope of variables as much as possible.

As for performance, it doesn't matter in the slightest. Since a local variable has automatic storage, the compiler will stack your variable just before it is used, no matter where the declaration appears in the source code.

That size_t would prevent the compiler from effectively optimizing your code is also nonsense.

Now what you *should* do, for scope and style reasons:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 42; i++)
```

And if this doesn't compile, you need to upgrade to a compiler which isn't older than 15 years.

Comment: Is this `for( type var = 0 ;;)` as `C99` or a `C11` feature?

Comment: It is a `c99` feature.

Comment: Wow, a perfect answer. I didn't see that coming.

Answer (score 1):

It is only about subjective matter of coding style. The both codes compiles equally to the same behaviour. One may preffer:

```
void foo(bool foobar) {
   size_t i;

   if (foobar) {
      for (i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
         // Do something
      }
   } 
}
```

as variable declaration is listed at the top. The second school is to declare variable closest to its usage (this code is perfectly valid in C89), so:

```
void foo(bool foobar) {
   if (foobar) {
      size_t i;
      for (i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
         // Do something
      }
   } 
}
```

can be preferred instead. Using a C99/C11 compiler it would be even to better to declare it directly in the `for` loop:

```
void foo(bool foobar) {
   if (foobar) {
      for (size_t i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
         // Do something
      }
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Old-style C (K&R) required all `auto` variables (in the old sense) to be declared at the beginning of the function after the part that set out the parameter types.

Newer standards (ANSI C) relax that, and modern coding conventions prefer keeping the scope of variables as tight as possible as that increases program stability.

I'd go one stage further and write (possible since C99)

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 42; i++)
```

as then the scope of `i` is limited to the `for` loop: there's no danger it will be relied upon in error in other parts of your program.

As for using `size_t` as the counter, I can't see why that would constrain a compiler's optimisation strategy. In fact, I'd suspect that `<` could be *faster* on unsigned types since you don't need to handle a sign bit.

Comment: Old-style C required all variables to be allocated at the beginning of the _block_. So C99 is not a concern here, because both versions of the original code will compile in C90.

Comment: Maybe my memory is wrong, but I'm sure *really* old C required them to be declared just after the function parameters.

Comment: Perhaps back in the dark ages before C90? My knowledge of those ancient times is limited :)

Comment: I'll check when I'm next in Cambridge. In the past I worked on K&R C (the professor disliked ANSI C), and we *always* declared the variables at the start of a function. Perhaps that was dogma and not demanded by the compilers at that time. We were all so obedient in those days ;-)